# Can GlassFish server 5.1 be started with JDK15?

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans, glassfish

I am working with Apache NetBeans IDE 12.0 to create Maven Web Application project template. I also downloaded JDK-15 and Glassfish server version 5.1 with Java EE 8 web.
I am writing my JSF code but when I run the page it shows that GlassFish server could not be started with JDK-15(default).Please select another jave SE platform.
Could you please help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure out this problem. I am exactly at the same situation.

Answer (score 4):

You have to download Java SE Development Kit 8u271 from this site :
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html. Then install it and set the enviromental variables as you do with jdk15. Then try to run your program and when you see the message "Please select another jave SE platform" choose the new jdk.
It work for me.